# Deleting with iteration in PHP

Tags: php, recursion, iteration, directory, delete-file

Here is my recursive file and folder remover function.

```
function rmdirRecursively($dir) {
    global $exc;
    $it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir),
                    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
    );

    $excludeDirsNames = array();
    $excludeFileNames = $exc["files"];

    foreach ($it as $entry) {
        if ($entry->isDir()) {
            if (!in_array($entry->getBasename(), $excludeDirsNames)) {
                try {
                    rmdir($entry->getPathname());
                } catch (Exception $ex) {
                    // dir not empty
                }
            }
        } elseif (!in_array($entry->getFileName(), $excludeFileNames)) {
            unlink($entry->getPathname());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm firing this function by sending parent directory name that must be deleted recursively (with all it's contents)

The problem is, I'm getting

> [07-Oct-2012 04:31:51] PHP Warning:  rmdir(./somefolder) [function.rmdir]: Directory not empty on line 69 ` RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST`

What am I missing?

Comment: What the error message says: the directory is not empty

Comment: @Gordon you don't say?:) What's solution?

Comment: making it empty before trying to delete it?

Comment: @Gordon I want to delete just as OS. I mean delete folder with all it's contents: files and folders

Comment: you have to empty the directory first. Only alternative would be `exec("rm -rf /path/to/somefolder")` but that is OS specific. On a sidenote, unless you use `-f` Linux wont allow you to delete non-empty directories either.

Comment: @Gordon shared hosting will not allow me to do it, I think. I need pure php, cross platform way

Comment: then empty the directory before trying to remove it :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17669/discussion-between-epic-syntax-and-gordon)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$excludeDirsNames = array('.', '..');
```

Else you would be trying to remove the current directory and parent directory before removing all its contents.

Comment: does it work if you don't exclude any files? Also, what's in $exc?

Answer (score 0):

List the files of the DIR first and delete them, then you will be able to remove the DIR

Comment: Those are already supposed to be deleted, since the iterator pushes them into the array first, and the script unlinks them before it gets to the directory

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function DelDir($dir)
{
  $d = dir($dir);
  while (false !== ($entry = $d->read()))
  {
    if (($entry != '.') && ($entry != '..'))
    {
      if (is_file($dir . '/' . $entry))
        unlink($dir . '/' . $entry);
      else
        DelDir($dir . '/' . $entry);
    }
  }
  $d->close();
  rmdir($dir);
}


DelDir('./test');
```